# How can I refactoring test code for both JavaScript and HTML requests\responses?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, rspec2

I am using Ruby on Rails 3.1.0 and the `rspec-rails 2`gem. Since I have to test both HTML and JavaScript requests for the same controller action and since sometime those responds by rendering *different* view files or behaving *differently*, I would like to refactor some code.

*Generally*, in my controller file I have:

```
def create
  ...
  respond_to
    format.html
    format.js
  end
end
```

At this time, in order to test both JS and HTML requests\responses, in my spec file I have *two different* examples (one example, for each case):

```
context "POST create" do
  let(:user) { User.new }

  it "should correctly respond to a JS request" do
    xhr :post, :create
    ...
    session[:user].should be_nil
    flash[:notice].should be_nil
  end

  it "should correctly respond to a HTML request" do
    post :create
    ...
    session[:user].should be_nil
    flash[:notice].should be_nil
  end
end
```

**How could\should I refactor the above code?**

Answer (score 2):

You could use `shared_examples_for`.

```
context "POST create" do
  let(:user) { User.new }

  shared_examples_for "a succesfull request" do
    it("does not set the user")  { session[:user].should be_nil }
    it("does not set the flash") { flash[:notice].should be_nil }
  end

  context "with a js request" do
    before(:each) do
      xhr :post, :create
    end

    it_should_behave_like "a succesfull request"
  end

  context "with a HTML request" do
    before(:each) do
      post :create 
    end

    it_should_behave_like "a succesfull request"
  end
end
```

Hope this helps.